# jquery remove/add class script doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Here is the jQuery script I am having a problem with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active")
        $(this).addClass("active")
    });
});
```

the script should make the background colour of the link /page you are in
to orange by using css programmed for the class (.)active
the script should remove the class active from the link that was active and add the class to the link that is clicked.

about how the script is supposed to do this:
if a li is clicked the thing with active class will have it's class removed,
than the clicked thing (this) wil gain the class active.
i used this but it seems it doesn't work

Comment: put a semicolumn after: $(".active").removeClass("active")

Comment: i tried that out but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Bb5uk/

Comment: is jQuery include in page? Are any errors thrown in console?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is copy paste error or not but you are missing semi-colon:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

**Update:**  Based on the comments I got to this response, I feel I should add that I stated that the semi-colon is missing because the code was all on one-line.  If that is NOT the case, then the semi-colon will not fix the problem.  With that said, there is nothing else wrong with the above code, so the error must be somewhere else on the page without enough information provided for us to fix it yet.

Comment: You don't need semi-colons with javascript: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: I know this, but if it were all on one line without line break, then you DO need semi-colon.  For me, I always add semi-colons to remove any doubt.

Comment: That's great advice, but it isn't the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("li").click(function(){ 
         $(this).parent("ul").find("li").removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass("active");
      }); 
   });
```

Also, don't forgot to add `;` at the end of line.

Comment: Sorry forgot bracket...check answer

Comment: why would that work if `$('.active').removeClass()` doesn't? Also could be too restrictive if there are neste UL's involved

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ? Can you clarify ?

Comment: I mean...if OP code not working...what does yours do to help? Also if there are multiple nested UL , like in a nav, yours may not traverse high enough only looking up to parent

Comment: It's finding the parent ul's li which has active class

Comment: @Ani Right, but if the original code, which found ALL elements with the active class, didn't work, then neither will yours.

Comment: hmm...i see what you mean. But OP is forgetting `;` :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jQuery expert but, if I understood your question well, this should worke... it did for me:

```
$('li').each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){
        DeselectCurrent();        
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});

var DeselectCurrent = function() {
    $('li').each(function(){
        var attr = $(this).attr('class');            

        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    });
};
```

Yes, I think it's kinda kludgy, and not as efficient as it probably should be, but it may solve what you're trying to do.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLxTb/) example